# Let $X$ be a locally compact Polish space. Is the space of continuous functions with compact support dense in that of $\mu$-integrable functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lp-spaces, polish-spaces

I'm reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66999/c-cx-dense-in-l-1x?rq=1) question for which I would like to clarify the theorem mentioned there. We have

- (S1) Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Then the space of continuous functions with *compact support* is dense in that of continuous functions *vanishing at infinity* w.r.t. $\| \cdot \|_\infty$. [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465216/space-of-continuous-functions-with-compact-support-dense-in-space-of-continuous#comment7850246_465216).
- (S2) Let $X$ be $\sigma$-compact, locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$. Then the space of continuous functions with *compact support* is dense in that of $\mu$-integrable functions w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_{L_1}$. [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66999/c-cx-dense-in-l-1x?rq=1)

Does (S2) still hold if we drop the $\sigma$-compactness condition? If not, does below statement hold?

> Let $X$ be a locally compact **Polish space** and $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $X$. Then the space of continuous functions with *compact support* is dense in that of $\mu$-integrable functions  w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_{L_1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, S2 holds without the assumption that $X$ be $\sigma$-compact. To see this, observe that the space of simple functions is dense in $L^1(\mu)$, so it suffices to show that simple functions can be approximated by functions in $C_c(X)$. Moreover,
if $g \in L^1$, the set $\{x \in X \, : \, g(x) \neq 0 \}$ is $\sigma$-finite, so in fact it suffices to show that a simple function $\chi_A$ with $\mu (A) < \infty$ can be approximated by an element of $C_c(X)$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\mu$ is Radon, for a $\mu$-finite set $A$ there exists a compact set $K$ and an open set $U$ such that $K \subset A \subset U$ and $\mu (U \setminus K) < \epsilon$. By Urysohn's lemma, one can choose an $f \in C_c(X)$ with $\chi_K \leq f \leq \chi_U$. It follows that
$$\|f - \chi_A \|_{L^1} \leq \mu (U \setminus K) < \epsilon$$
as desired.

Comment: Could you explain what it means for a set to be $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @Akira A set $A$ is $\sigma$-finite for $\mu$ if it admits a decomposition $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$ such that $\mu (E_i) < \infty$ for each $i$. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821538/if-f-is-integrable-then-x-in-x-mid-fx-neq-0-is-sigma-finite

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: A Borel measure $\mu$ on a Hausdorff topological space $X$ is called Radon if $\mu$ is tight and locally finite. In (S2), $X$ is locally compact, so $\mu$ is also outer regular. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is a LCH space, $\mu$ is outer regular.

Comment: Ah I guess you meant if $X$ is a LCH space, **finite** Radon measures are outer regular.

Comment: @Akira In fact, more is true. Since you have a locally compact Polish space, every open set is $\sigma$-compact, so that any Borel measure that is locally finite is (inner and outer) regular. See Theorem 7.8 in Folland's Real Analysis.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you use Urysohn's [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma#Formal_Statement) to construct such $f$?

Comment: @Akira Use Urysohn's lemma to get a function that is $1$ on $K$ and $0$ on $U^c$.

Comment: Compact Hausdorff space is normal. If X is only locally compact, does Urysohn's lemma work?